# Remove only multiple brackets

Tags: r

I have string in this form

```
"[1425]", "[[12545]]", "2423", "((125))", "[[[1543]]]", "(1432)"
```

I tried the solutions in the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24993337/r-remove-only-from-string), but it is not working for this case.  I need

```
"[1425]", "[12545]", "2423", "(125)", "[1543]", "(1432)"
```

ie. remove the multiples of bracket present.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
library(stringr)
v1 <- c("[1425]", "[[12545]]", "2423", "((125))", "[[[1543]]]", "(1432)")

str_extract(v1, "\\D?[0-9]+\\D?")
#[1] "[1425]"  "[12545]" "2423"    "(125)"   "[1543]"  "(1432)"
```

Answer (score 0):

And the award for most unreadable answer goes to:

```
x <- c("[1425]", "[[12545]]", "2423", "((125))", "[[[1543]]]", "(1432)")
gsub("(\\[|\\]|\\(|\\))\\1+","\\1",x)
#[1] "[1425]"  "[12545]" "2423"    "(125)"   "[1543]"  "(1432)"
```